# Documents.Add results in template being locked

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a macro that creates a new document based on a template stored on a network share. This macro is stored in each user's Word\STARTUP folder as the file "macros.dotm" and is executed by a button added to a toolbar.

The template file gets locked as soon as the macro code is executed and stays locked so long as the derivative document is still open by another user.

It has no impact on their ability to open new documents based on the macro, but if I want to edit the template, I have to ask them to close Word (and hope nobody else goes into it).

Macro code:

```
Documents.Add Template:="F:\templates\letterhead.dotm", NewTemplate:=False, DocumentType:=0`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that the template is on a network drive - this is a pretty common issue. One way to get around it is to have your calling template copy over that template locally first and then create a new doc based off of that (and then delete the template when done).

Comment: If the template provides code or UI customization to the documents created from it, I'd skip the deletion and replace the local copy with a fresh copy from the network drive as needed when the user initiates creating a document for the template again. Take care to handle the situation where the user already has a document created from the template open and trys to make a new one.

Answer (score 3):

One way around this is detaching the document from the template after it is generated:

```
Dim doc As Document
Set doc = Documents.Add(Template:="F:\templates\letterhead.dotm", NewTemplate:=False, DocumentType:=0)
Set doc.AttachedTemplate = Nothing
```

Alternatively, change the filesystem permissions on the template so only you have write access.

Comment: Hate to take it away, but I'm getting a syntax error on `Set doc.AttachedTemplate = Nothing` stating, "Run-time error '5946': 'Name' is not a by reference property."

Comment: Ok, I was able to get it to work by changing `doc.AttachedTemplate = ""`, which a MsgBox confirms it defaults it back to Normal.dotm.  However, the template is still locked, so this method doesn't work.

Comment: Oops I should test the code before I post it.  I am surprised it doesn't release the lock with your version.